# Use Alias in other column in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, alias

I am looking to do some basic math on my `SELECT` query and columns..

```
SELECT Rider, 
COUNT(if(Result = 1, Result, NULL)) AS "Firsts", 
COUNT(if(Result = 2, Result, NULL)) AS "Seconds", 
COUNT(if(Result = 3, Result, NULL)) AS "Thirds", 
COUNT(if(Result = " ", Result, NULL)) AS "NP",
COUNT(*) AS "Total",
"Firsts"/"Total"*100 AS "S/R"
FROM meeting_master
WHERE RaceDayDate>="2012-01-01"
GROUP BY meeting_master.Rider
ORDER BY Firsts DESC
LIMIT 100
```

My problem (and lack of MySQL knowledge) is to have the `S/R` column calculate the math in the 7th line...

Comment: Your problem is unclear. What exactly you want to calculate for `S/R` column?

Comment: sorry.. typed in a rush.  I'd like to calculate a new column "S/R" based on values from "Firsts" and "Total".  At the moment i either get NULL or 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use *alias* in `SELECT` like this:

```
"Firsts"/"Total"*100 AS "S/R"
```

Instead calculate directly like this:

```
COUNT(if(Result = 1, Result, NULL))/COUNT(*) * 100 AS "S/R"
```

So your query should be:

```
SELECT Rider, 
COUNT(if(Result = 1, Result, NULL)) AS "Firsts", 
COUNT(if(Result = 2, Result, NULL)) AS "Seconds", 
COUNT(if(Result = 3, Result, NULL)) AS "Thirds", 
COUNT(if(Result = " ", Result, NULL)) AS "NP",
COUNT(*) AS "Total",
COUNT(if(Result = 1, Result, NULL))/COUNT(*) * 100 AS "S/R"
FROM meeting_master
WHERE RaceDayDate>="2012-01-01"
GROUP BY meeting_master.Rider
ORDER BY Firsts DESC
LIMIT 100
```

[Just see SQLFiddle example here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff99b/15)

Comment: awesome.. thanks!  i should have approached it that way... cheers for the xtra tips too!